# Install CDH 6.0.1 have trouble with install cm-agent

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

with cloudera install doc step by step I have in trouble with Install Agents
like this:
[image]

It said install failed and can not receive signal.
And I find the log like this:

```
    [13/Nov/2018 16:44:19 +0000] 4306 MainThread agent        ERROR    Heartbeating to ryze-1.bigdata.com:7182 failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/agent.py", line 1371, in _send_heartbeat
    response = self.requestor.request('heartbeat', heartbeat_data)
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/ipc.py", line 141, in request
    return self.issue_request(call_request, message_name, request_datum)
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/ipc.py", line 254, in issue_request
    call_response = self.transceiver.transceive(call_request)
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/ipc.py", line 483, in transceive
    result = self.read_framed_message()
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/ipc.py", line 489, in read_framed_message
    framed_message = response_reader.read_framed_message()
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/ipc.py", line 417, in read_framed_message
    raise ConnectionClosedException("Reader read 0 bytes.")
ConnectionClosedException: Reader read 0 bytes.
```

I try to solve it with google I already check these setting.

1. /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini the port set `7182` and server_host set `ryze-1.bigdata.com`.
2. iptable altready shutdown with `sudo service iptables stop`
3. ryze-1.bigdata.com is reachable. and `telnet ryze-1.bigdata.com 7183` can succeed.

OS: Centos7.4
Platform: AliCloud

So what can I do? Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I closed the ssl option.
Everything is fine now.......